# fluentd and nginx access log format

Tags: regex, nginx, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

how can I write the regex for the following nginx access log format in fluentd ?

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $request '
                        '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_HOST" $HOST '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                        'upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time '
                        'upstream_addr $upstream_addr '
                          'msec $msec request_time $request_time';
```

Answer (score -1):

This is easy with [nginx fluend module](https://github.com/fluent/nginx-fluentd-module).

The module send access logs to fluentd via fluentd-udp-plugin realtime, the log format is json, you can get all log variables in fluentd.

Comment: Links only answer aren't welcome on SO. Could you provide an excerpt of the content you are linking to?

Comment: thanks, but i can't recompile nginx right now i need the regular expression for my log format.